# Regular expression finding '\n'

Tags: python, regex

I'm in the process of making a program to pattern match phone numbers in text.

I'm loading this text:

```
(01111-222222)fdf
01111222222
(01111)222222
01111 222222
01111.222222
```

Into a variable, and using "findall" it's returning this:

```
('(01111-222222)', '(01111', '-', '222222)')
('\n011112', '', '\n', '011112')
('(01111)222222', '(01111)', '', '222222')
('01111 222222', '01111', ' ', '222222')
('01111.222222', '01111', '.', '222222')
```

This is my expression:

```
ex = re.compile(r"""(
    (\(?0\d{4}\)?)?       # Area code
    (\s*\-*\.*)?          # seperator
    (\(?\d{6}\)?)        # Local number
     )""", re.VERBOSE)
```

I don't understand why the '\n' is being caught.

If `*` in '`\\.*`' is substituted for by '`+`', the expression works as I want it. Or if I simply remove `*`(and being happy to find the two sets of numbers separated by only a single period), the expression works.

Comment: `\s*` include `\n`

Comment: Dot `.` does not match a newline unless the `re.DOTALL` (or `re.S`) flag is set.

Comment: I've just realised my last paragraph is in fact, not true. I didn't view my results properly at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\s` matches both *horizontal* and *veritcal* whitespace symbols. If you have a `re.VERBOSE`, you can match a normal space with an escaped space `\` . Or, you may exclude `\r` and `\n` from `\s` with `[^\S\r\n]` to match horizontal whitespace.

Use

```
ex = re.compile(r"""(
    (\(?0\d{4}\)?)?       # Area code
    ([^\S\r\n]*-*\.*)?   # seperator   ((HERE))
    (\(?\d{6}\)?)        # Local number
     )""", re.VERBOSE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TefKkm/3)

Also, the `-` outside a character class does not require escaping.